# facebook api how do you take action(like/comment) on a page's feed on that page's behalf

Tags: php, facebook, api

Hopefully the title makes sense...

what I am trying to do is comment on a post of the page using that page instead of the user commenting on the page's post. However, I have tried giving it the page access token along with the comment post but it does not do anything.

```
$request = new FacebookRequest(
            $this->facebook->get_session(),
            'POST',
            '/'.$id.'/comments',
            array (
                'message' => $comment,
                'access_token' => $token
            )
        );

        $response = $request->execute();
        $result = $response->getResponse();
```

The access token for the page was my last real idea that makes any sense to me and I cannot seem to find it within the api docs, or a question on here.

Suggestions are welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a "Page Access Token". You create it by using `[/me/accounts][1]`, it will list all your Pages including an Access Token for each of them.

More information about Access Tokens:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/extended-page-access-tokens-curl/

Comment: Thank you for your time but I have figured it out and as I had mentioned I knew I had to have the access token I just didn't see what I was doing wrong, but it was an error in my code which you wouldn't have been able to see(since I didn't post everything).